# Having trouble with scipy.optimize.leastsq

Tags: optimization, scipy

I am new to optimization and having trouble using the least squares minimization.
Here is the code I have tried so far:

def func(tpl, x):
    return 1./exp(x/360. * tpl)

def errfunc(tpl, x, y):
    func(tpl,x) - y

//x-axis

xdata = np.array([181,274])

//minimize sum(y - func(x))**2

ydata = np.array([0.992198836646864,0.992996067735572])

//initial guesses

tplInitial1 = (0.031, 0.032)
popt, pcov = leastsq(errfunc, tplInitial1[:], args=(xdata, ydata))
print popt

I was hoping to get [0.032359,0.03071] returned by the minimize function but getting "only lenght-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars".
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is that the actual code your executing? `//` is not Python comment syntax!

Comment: `errfunc` doesn't have a `return` statement, so it returns `None`.  Presumably the body of the function should be `return func(tpl,x) - y`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are using `math.exp` instead of `numpy.exp` (i.e. the scalar version instead of the array version). Try using `from numpy import exp`.